# Save content in a modal window as varbinary in SQL Server table

Tags: c#, asp.net, varbinary

Scenario:

An aspx (modal) window is constructed at runtime by different ascx's (I'm retrieving the information on which ascx to load from a SQL Server table).

I have a placeholder on the aspx page, and all the `UserControls` are added to the placeholder using `LoadControl(control_name)`

The end user of this screen will read the content and sign it on a touchscreen device (saying, I consent to the information above).

Requirement:

After signing and the user hits "Submit" button, the complete content on the modal aspx page should be converted to a varbinary suitable format. I'm facing challenges in achieving this requirement.

What I have tried:

1. `iTextSharp` (`RenderControl` is causing issues as some of the ascx's have complex controls in them)
2. Telerik's `RadClientExportManager`. It works amazingly well if there's an "Export to PDF" button on client-side and an end user clicks it, but I'm having trouble to get that data on to the server side.
3. I tried loading all controls to an editor, just to utilize the options like `ExportToPdf()` on the server-side, but the UX was not elegant.

Can anyone please help me with this? Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not totally sure, but it seems you should show the code of your attempts so that we can help. Especially the second option: "I'm having trouble to get that data on to the server side" is too vague, you should post your code, expected and actual behaviour, error messages and other necessary details. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest on the click event you use Javascript to capture the HTML you want to save and send it back to the server by whatever method suits you the most, ajax, API call or even a callback panel.

Once there you should be able to pass the text/markup into what process you require at that point.

I hope that helps and welcome :D

Comment: Awesome! Thank you, @Mayhem50. I implemented it through ajax call.